# Expected number of draws with replacement until a repeat draw

Tags: probability, expectation

> An urn contains $n$ balls numbered. We draw one ball, examine its number, and replace it in the urn. We repeat this until we draw any ball for the second time. Let $X$ the number of draws for this to happen (the two draws of the same ball do not have to be consecutive). Determine the distribution of X

For example, if we draw the ball $i$, and replace it in the urn, then $X$ is the number of repetitions needed to draw the same ball $i$ for the second time. I need determine a distribution for $X$, where $X$ takes on values $\{1,2,3\cdots,k\}$ (i.e., on the $k$th draw we select the same ball for the second time). Then $P(X\geq k)$ is the probability we do not draw the same ball in $\{1,2,\cdots,k-1\}$. But this means $n\choose k-1$ ways; I'm not sure this is true, any help? It's my first post here!

Comment: It is difficult to believe that the highlighted part is a question quoted exactly, I can't make heads or tails of it !

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to edit the question for better English; based on the expression, I believe that the edit is (will be) correct, but please let me know if I've misinterpreted your intent.

Comment: Oh thanks for edit the question. But I refer that "no matter if I take the same ball consecutively". Regards

Comment: @user123456789: I intended "the two draws of the same ball do not have to be consecutive" to cover that.  Is that not what you meant?  It seems to yield the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

We obviously draw the first time with probability $1$.  We draw the second time with probability $\frac{n}{n} = 1$ also.

But we continue on to the third draw only if the second ball did not match the first ball, which it does with probability $\frac{1}{n}$.  Thus we continue to the third draw with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

We then continue on to the fourth draw only if the third ball did not match either of the first two balls, which it does with probability $\frac{2}{n}$.  We therefore continue on to the fourth draw with probability $\frac{n-2}{n}$.

In general, we continue from the $k$th draw to the $k+1$th draw only if the $k$th ball did not match any of the first $k-1$ balls, which it does with probability $\frac{k-1}{n}$.  We therefore continue with probability $\frac{n-k+1}{n}$.

The greatest number of draws we can have is $n+1$ (by the pigeonhole principle), after which we continue with probability $\frac{0}{n} = 0$.  Our expectation for the total number of draws is therefore

\begin{align}
EX & = 1+\frac{n}{n}\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\left(1+\frac{n-2}{n}\left(1+\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)\right) \\
   & = 2+\frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot\frac{n-3}{n}+\cdots+\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

which is the desired expression.

Comment: Yes, for me make me sense. But What can say about the distribution of $X$??

Comment: And why "The greatest number of draws we can have is $n+1$"??

Comment: To answer your second question first, suppose you have balls $1$ through $n$.  How can you possibly draw more than $n$ balls without duplicating at least one number?

Comment: To the first question: $X = 2$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$.  $X = 3$ with probability $\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2}$.  $X = 4$ with probability $\frac{3(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3}$.  And in general, $X = k$ with probability $\frac{(k-1)n!}{n^k(n-k+1)!}$, for $2 \leq k \leq n+1$.

Comment: Ohh great answer, but I cannot see why X=3 with probability $2(n-1)/n^2$. Thanks

Comment: It's the product of $(n-1)/n$ (the probability of getting to the third draw) and $2/n$ (the probability, given that you get to the third draw, that it matches one of the first two).  See above for more detailed reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Both your quoted problem and your own text are difficult to understand.  It sounds like you are drawing balls with replacement and asking the probability distribution of the number of draws until some ball is drawn for a second time.  Clearly the chance of a duplicate on the first draw is zero.  What is the chance the first two draws are the same?  For the first duplicate to be on the third draw you need to have drawn two different balls on the first two draws, then match one of the two on the third draw.  Then for the first match to be on the fourth draw, the first three must be different, then the fourth must match one of the three.  Can you formalize this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Now I edited my question, sorry for the wrong question.

Comment: "until the first ball is drawn for a second time" > "until the first time any ball is drawn for the second time"

Comment: "the some ball" ? Not any better.

Answer (score 1):

Inasmuch as $\frac{\binom nkk!}{n^k}$ is the probability of no repetition in the first $k$ draws (so that the $k+1^{\text{st}}$ draw takes place), the expected number of draws is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom nkk!}{n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

On the first draw the probability is zero, on the second it is $\frac{1}{n},$ on the third $\frac{2}{n}$ and so on until the $n+1$st ball where the probability is $1.$

However for a stage to be reached all previous stages must fail to repeat a ball, so the probability of stage k is:

$\frac{k-1}{n} \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \left(1-\frac{j-1}{n}\right)$

I am sure this can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but If I can determine the density of $X$, 
I should prove that the expected value is  $E(X)=2+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\cdots+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$, but I can not prove this Regards