# Asymptotics of expected number of draws until repeat

Tags: probability, summation, asymptotics, birthday

Suppose there are $n$ distinct balls in a bag and they are drawn with replacement until the first repeat. Let $X$ be the number of balls drawn. I have shown that the distribution is unimodal and that the mode is asymptotically equal to $\sqrt n$. The expectation of the distribution is derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610327/expected-number-of-draws-with-replacement-until-a-repeat-draw) to be

$$
\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k} \frac{k!}{n^k}
$$

I believe that this also should asymptotically equal $\sqrt n$ or $C \sqrt n$ for some $C$, and my numerical experiments have confirmed this. Is this true and why?

Comment: Your $C$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people_to_get_at_least_one_shared_birthday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A derivation can be found in this paper.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042793E0258N?via%3Dihub

Comment: just a complement : check "birthday problem", many textbooks have a section on this (perhaps more appropriate for the MSE level).